# Android package name changed

Tags: android, manifest

I've changed the package name of my android app using: *Android Tools-->Rename Application Package*  in my project.

Now, when I launch my application, I get this error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

Logcat output is empty...How can I solve this issue?

Comment: post your manifest file code

Comment: `@Stephan Branczyk is right.`

Answer (score 1):

Check your package name in your manifest.xml file. You may also need to change what is written in front of the "package=". Like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.name.package.new.your"
```

Comment: the package name matches. Any other tip?

Answer (score 0):

You look through your manifest.xml file. The problem should be pretty obvious. And if you can't find the problem yourself, you post the manifest file on here.

Eclipse often has problems with this very issue.

Comment: I have another question: should the "package name" in manifest be the same of the package of my launcher activity?

Comment: Ah! You're actually paying attention. That's good. Technically, there should be at least two package names, one for the application and at least one for the activities. Most beginner android developers believe that there is only one package name, but that's only because the New Android Project's wizard only makes you enter one package name that it will use twice. Knowing this little tidbit of information, that there are always at least two package names -- even if they're identical (although, they don't have to be), can be very important. Be sure to file it away in your brain for later on.